# Are there any official statements about soya based protein or are there just opinions and contradictory findings?

Tags: proteins

Is there any current official statement about soya based protein related health risks, or is it like with climate change, some parties can prove it, some can disprove.

Comment: Who claims that soy protein poses health risks?

Comment: Huffington Post published series of articles on differenr studies; I cannot estimate how much truthful or not all this information is.

Comment: I would assume [this](https://www.huffingtonpost.com/dr-mercola/soy-health_b_1822466.html) is the article you're referring to. The first thing I see is it was written by Joseph Mercola, which immediately means it has no credibility and isn't worth reading. But I skimmed it anyway and I see he makes many alarming claims about soy with the only supporting evidence being links to articles on his own web site written by him. Citing himself is exactly what I would expect from him. I recommend you find a better source of scary things to read.